# Configuring a network on a multi ethernet port server

Tags: networking, server, dhcp

Hy to all: I have just installed Ubuntu Server 12.04.3 on a Sunfire X4100

This server has 4 ethernet port, my target is to use:

- eth0 to connect to the modem and so to internet
- eth1, eth2, eth3 to connect some switch and access point in order to create an   internal lan, share resources, storage, printers, etc.

To achive this target I installed a dhcp server [apt-get install isc-dhcp-server] and used below configuration:

```
/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server
 INTERFACES="eth1 eth2 eth3"

/etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
  iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
    iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.5
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.1.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

auto eth1
    iface eth1 inet static
    address 192.168.1.5
    netmaks 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.1.0

auto eth2
    iface eth2 inet static
    address 192.168.1.5
    netmaks 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.1.0

auto eth3
    iface eth3 inet static
    address 192.168.1.5
    netmaks 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.1.0
```

my DHCP-Server configuration

```
/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255;
option routers 192.168.1.1;
option netbios-name-servers 192.168.1.1;
# Use Google public DNS
option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
option domain-name "mydomain.it";
# Define address range
subnet 192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
   range 192.168.2.15 192.168.2.25;
}
```

The result is:

- Server has the desired ip address and is capable to go on internet
- Client machines receive the ip address from the DHCP but are not able
  to go over internet and/or either ping server or modem

Here-below ip ad result on the server:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:14:4f:20:20:9c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.5/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::214:4fff:fe20:209c/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:14:4f:20:20:9d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.5/32 scope global eth1
    inet6 fe80::214:4fff:fe20:209d/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: eth2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:14:4f:20:20:a2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.3.5/32 scope global eth2
5: eth3: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:14:4f:20:20:a3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.4.5/32 scope global eth3
6: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN 
    link/ether 06:0d:62:1a:3c:c5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
```

here below ip r on the server:

```
 default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0  metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth3  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.2 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.122.1
```

Here below a picture of the map:

[image: Network Picture]

Comment: You're setting all four interface to the same IP address?  That's a recipe for trouble.

Comment: I have added my /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf

Comment: Ouch - eth1,eth2, eth3 have "NO Carrier" - strange. Therefore there is no route to these networks either. Cabling issue?

Comment: @user234441 can you confirm that cables are plugged in?

Comment: I verified: cables were disconnected when I run the command ...

Comment: @user234441 please replace your `ip ad` and `ip r` results above with those where the cables are actually connected - its hard to diagnose settings with disconnected cables.

Comment: I have done just for eth0: please let me know if you need further info

Comment: @user234441 eth0? I think it was eth1. You don't have any routes for your eth1, eth2, eth3. type `sudo ip route add 192.168.2.0/24 via 192.168.2.5 dev eth2` and then try again.

Comment: sorry typo you are right: eth1

Comment: I tried and it worked at first shoot! Now I just need to make it permanent for all ports. Thanks a lot for your strong support

Comment: how can I make the routing permanet? I tried with post-up /sbin/route add 192.168.2.0/24 via 192.168.2.5 dev eth1 in /etc/network/interfaces but doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1) configure the networks

Apart from the DHCP-part (and the forwarding darent suggested) you need to configure your interfaces correctly.

In most cases each interface is in its own IP-network (I am giving example-addresses, you will have to adapt them).

Leave `eth0` as it is.

```
auto eth1
  iface eth1 inet static
  address 192.168.2.5
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  network 192.168.2.0

auto eth2
  iface eth2 inet static
  address 192.168.3.5
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  network 192.168.3.0

auto eth3
  iface eth3 inet static
  address 192.168.4.5
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  network 192.168.4.0
```

If the DHCP server is running on the same machine you will have to configure it accordingly. Just for testing you can give one host on every subnet a static IP-address (for instance use `192.168.2.11` for one host connected to `eth1`)

After having configured IP-networks and IP-addresses correctly you will need to enable IP-forwarding with

```
sudo sh -c "echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward"
```

(just for once to test success)

and by editing `/etc/sysctl.conf` and "activating" the line

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

by removing the `#` at the beginning.

When that is done (every client should be able to ping the corresponding interface of your server)

### 2) activate NAT

(try it first for one subnet, I give the example for `eth1` you have to adapt addresses for the other ones)

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o eth0 -i eth1 -s 192.168.2.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Now the clients on subnet 1 should be able to ping IP-addresses on the internet - but only till the next reboot of your server. If it works continue with `eth2` and `eth3` accordingly.

To make it permanent you need to save the current (working) configuration of netfilter rules

```
sudo iptables-save | sudo tee /etc/iptables-NAT.sav
```

and then create the following entry in `/etc/rc.local` to reload the same configuration on every reboot. Make sure that `exit 0` is **after** your new entry

```
iptables-restore < /etc/iptables-NAT.sav
```

(no `sudo` needed here)

### 3) DHCP

The DHCP-Configuration is wrong. You must create different subnets for every interface **and** you must set an appropriate "gateway" (using `option routers`) for each subnet.

```
# for eth1 with 192.168.2.5 as local address
subnet 192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
range 192.168.2.15 192.168.2.25;
option routers 192.168.2.5;
} 
# for eth2 with 192.168.3.5 as local address
subnet 192.168.3.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
range 192.168.3.15 192.168.3.25;
option routers 192.168.3.5;
} 
# for eth3 with 192.168.4.5 as local address
subnet 192.168.4.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
range 192.168.4.15 192.168.4.25;
option routers 192.168.4.5;
}
```

Now all clients should be able to reach IP-addresses outside your network, name-resolution will (probably) not be available yet.

Comment: I tried but same situation. Is there any think that I should check? Thanks

Comment: @user234441 I extended my answer.

Comment: thanks: tried but problem persists: ip correctly assigned but if I try to ping inside the network the results is: Destination Host Unreachable as well as not possible to reach the router and go on internet

Comment: @user234441 I extended my answer once more, to address your DHCP-issues. And please delete your comment above - the information is safely in your question :-)

Comment: @user234441 does it work for the subnet on `eth1`? You have to enter the commands one after another.

Comment: I tried but doesn't work: one strange thing if I set static ip on a PC and connect on eth0 I'm able to ping the server but the server doesn't ping the machine with fix ip. If I do the same on eth1 nothing works. Any other suggerstion?

Comment: Done: for testing purposes I replaced one AP with one PC with fixed ip address. This pc is able to ping the server but not the opposite

Comment: Can you explain what does the 0/24 means in the NAT server configuration. I tried and I'm able to ping the Access Point with setting above but not the server. Any other suggestion?

Comment: @user234441 `-s 192.168.2.0/24` means all packages with source addresses from `192.168.2.1` to `192.168.2.254` (i.e. `netmask 255.255.255.0`)

Comment: I verified that also ufw is disabled. Is there something obvious that I have forgotten? Ping returns: Destination Host Unreachable

Comment: Using your inputs now everything is working fine, I have only one problem: I can't connect to a network printer or projector on a subnet from a different subnet. I can ping them but not connect. Any suggestion? What am I missing?

Comment: @user234441 about connecting from another subnet - please ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable IP forwarding on the server so the packages from the hosts can reach the WAN:

```
sudo sysctl net/ipv4/ip_forward=1
```

Try this, and then try to ping an external IP or URL from the hosts.